# How do I adjust for a recipe to bake in an oven instead of on a grill?

Tags: baking, temperature

I have a recipe for grilling a pear crisp that calls for grilling for 15 to 20 minutes over indirect medium heat.

Can I instead bake this in an oven?  At what temperature should I bake it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You want it to brown, so I'd do it at about 375 or 400 Fahrenheit. Depending on how thick and wet it is, it could take anywhere from say 20 to 40 minutes. If you have a thermometer, you can figure it is done at say 180 degrees in the center. Otherwise just look for bubbling juices and a nice brown top.

Answer (score 1):

I think 375-400 might be a bit too hot, and the topping would get too brown before the pears cooked down. I'd try 350 degrees Fahrenheit, for the first time.